# How to add a record after a UNION query

Tags: mysql, union, iteration

I have the UNION query below that works perfectly.
The data from the UNION query is displayed in a grid.
I also have an ITERATIVE *add* query which allows the user to add multiple records.
Since I created the UNION query,
the ADD Query no longer works.
How would I accomplish the add (iterative) after the UNION?
Both queries are below.

**UNION QUERY**

```
SELECT
submissions.user, submissions.statusid, submissions.no, submissions.Name,    
submissions.monthid, submissions.yearid, submissions.dateupdated
FROM submissions 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN name ON submissions.no = name.no
WHERE submissions = SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(status),statusid
FROM status WHERE statusid = 1 ORDER BY status
AND submissions.monthid = SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(month),monthid
FROM month ORDER BY monthid
AND submissions.yearid = SELECT year FROM year ORDER BY Yearid

UNION 

SELECT
name.user, name.statusid, name.no, name.Name, name.area,
name.monthid, name.yearid, name.dateupdated
FROM name
LEFT OUTER JOIN submissions ON name.no = submissions.no
```

**ADD QUERY (ITERATIVE)**

```
 /* Set the Status ID */
SET @statusid = submissions.statusid
 /* Set the Month ID */
SET @monthid = submissions.monthid
 /* Set the Month ID */
SET @yearid = submissions.yearid
/* Set the User ID */
SET @user = <code type="user" attribute="id" />
/* Set the Date Updated */
SET @dateupdated = NOW()
/* Insert records iteratively */
/* @user, @statusid, no, name, area, @monthid, @yearid,  
@dateupdated */
INSERT INTO submissions
SELECT @user, @statusid, s.no, s.name, s.area, @monthid, @yearid, 
@dateupdated
FROM school_submissions s
```

The add query keeps giving me the following error: "No input for 'no'".
It's basically not 'picking up' the 'no' from the grid,
thus it can't INSERT the record into the table.
Since the UNION query,
the ADD query is not able to find each No, Name, and Area.

How can I get past this issue?

Comment: Can we see the query without all that other stuff?

Comment: you are performing a left outter join from name to submissions.  This means that submission information can be null, which would very much look like "it R not picking up the submission info"

Comment: Yes, i want to see Everything from Submissions and Everything from name. The UNION part works correctly. I need help with the ITERATION thereafter.

Comment: RIGHT JOINS. Isn't it nice to see someone using them